# MPD fails to start the next song

Tags: linux, alsa, mpd

I am running Arch Linux (e17) on x86_64; with mpd 0.17.3 and ALSA 10.0.26.

One update ~three months ago mpd started acting strange. It would not start playing the next song, and it would appear as if there is a file lock on the sound device from the previous song which causes the player to fail starting the next. No relevant message appears in /var/log/mpd/mpd.log

I am a bit clueless about why it works like that. The daemon is running on its own user which is in the "audio" user group. Here is the relevant snippet from /etc/mpd.conf:

```
audio_output {
         type            "alsa"
         name            "My ALSA Device"
         device          "hw:0,0"        # optional
         format          "44100:16:2"    # optional
#        mixer_device    "default"       # optional
#        mixer_control   "PCM"           # optional
#        mixer_index     "0"             # optional
}
```

The last three are commented because mpd ignores them when they are uncommented. I should mention that the flashplayer (adobe's) used to have problems locking the sound card, but sometime around the update that broke mpd, the flashplayer started acting nice. Perhaps the two are related somehow?

I will be happy to provide more relevant data, but I'm not sure what would that be.

Thanks!

Comment: Using the device directly like `hw:0,0` will only allow one thing to use the device at once. Setting up dmix properly in `~/.asoundrc` might help. I don't know if crossfade in MPD would cause it to lock up like that, I've never had any issues with MPD not playing the next song. When I get home, if there's no solution yet, I'll change my config to use `hw:0,0` instead of `pcm.default` (or `default`, I can't remember from the top of my head) and see if I can recreate it. Would you mind sharing the whole `mpd.conf` as well as any alsa config you've done (`~/.asoundrc`)

Comment: @Rob: This occurs even when the device line is commented out; and regardless to cross-fade. I don't mind mpd locking the sound for *other* applications, but for itself? Sounds strange!